# Adjust font size FPDF

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

In FPDF I have a cell with a width of 176mm where I need to put a client name. The problem is that the client name doesn always adjust to that fixed width. Is there a way to make the font size of the cell autoadjust to the cell width in case it is too long?

This is the code that I have right now:

```
$pdf->Cell( 116, 7, utf8_decode( $row_or[ 'client_name' ] ), 0, 0, 'L' );
```

I know that TCPDF has a way to set the auto-stretch but i have not found any for FPDF. Do I have to do it with code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, it turns out that there is a function called GetStringWidth which receives a string and returns itś width in milimeters, so, what i did was:

```
/* I know that the font size starts with 11, so i set a variable at this size */
$x = 11;    // Will hold the font size
/* I will cycle decreasing the font size until it's width is lower than the max width */
while( $pdf->GetStringWidth( utf8_decode( $row_or[ 'client_name' ] ) ) > 116 ){
    $x--;   // Decrease the variable which holds the font size
    $pdf->SetFont( 'Trebuchet', 'B', $x );  // Set the new font size
}
/* Output the string at the required font size */
$pdf->Cell( 116, 7, utf8_decode( $row_or[ 'client_name' ] ) ), 0, 0, 'L' );
/* Return the font size to itś original */
$pdf->SetFont( 'Trebuchet', 'B', 11 );
```

Comment: $pdf->SetFont( 'Trebuchet', 'B', --$x );  // Decrement and then set the new font size in one line

Answer (score 1):

The decrease can be fractions of points too for finer columns adjustment, like:
  $x-=0.1;
instead of $x--;